# VMinsight enable Azure VM using PowerShell

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-monitoring, azure-monitor

I am trying to push AMA (Azure Monitoring Agent ) via PowerShell automation to Azure Windows VMs. Looking at Microsoft documentation currently its only available via Portal or ARM templates. This documentation gives the script https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/vm/vminsights-enable-powershell but with old version of LA Agents not via the DCR Rules.

How can I write a PowerShell script to create DCR rules, apply to VMs of subscriptions, and install the latest AMA agent?

Answer (score 0):

> How can I write a PowerShell script to create DCR rules, apply to VMs of subscriptions, and install the latest AMA agent?

Here is a PowerShell script to create a `DCR` rule and apply the rule to all `VM's` in `Subscription`.

```
Connect-AzAccount -Subscription "Subscription-Name"
Install-Module Az.Monitor
Import-Module Az.Monitor
$resourceGroup = "venkattests-resources"
$dcrRule = New-AzDataCollectionRule -Location "eastus" -ResourceGroupName "Resource-Group-Name" -RuleName "Install-Agent" -RuleFile "DCR.json"
$dcr = Get-AzDataCollectionRule -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup -RuleName $dcrRule.Name
#Get all VM's in Subscription
$Vms = Get-AzVM
foreach ($vm in $Vms) {
    $vmId = $vm.Id
    $VmName = $vm.Name
    $dcrname = $DcrRule.Name
    Write-Host "Applying DCR Rule Name: $dcrname to VM Name: $VmName " 
    
    #Apply the DCR to all VM's in Subscription
    New-AzDataCollectionRuleAssociation -TargetResourceId $vmId -AssociationName "DCRRule" -RuleId $dcr.Id
}
}
```

I have followed this [Ms-Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.monitor/new-azdatacollectionrule?view=azps-10.3.0&tryIt=true&source=docs#syntax) to create **Data Collection Rule**

**DCR.json**

```json
    {
      "properties": {
        "dataSources": {
          "performanceCounters": [
            {
              "streams": [
                "Microsoft-InsightsMetrics"
              ],
              "scheduledTransferPeriod": "PT1M",
              "samplingFrequencyInSeconds": 10,
              "counterSpecifiers": [
                "\\Processor Information(_Total)\\% Processor Time"
              ],
              "name": "perfCounter01"
            }
          ]
        },
        "destinations": {
          "azureMonitorMetrics": {
            "name": "azureMonitorMetrics-default"
          }
        },
        "dataFlows": [
          {
            "streams": [
              "Microsoft-InsightsMetrics"
            ],
            "destinations": [
              "azureMonitorMetrics-default"
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
```

**Output:**

[image]

Reference: [Create data collection rule association](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.monitor/new-azdatacollectionruleassociation?view=azps-10.3.0) &
[Create a data collection rule](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.monitor/new-azdatacollectionrule?view=azps-10.3.0&tryIt=true&source=docs#code-try-1).